# What is "n" in TSC? Is this any particular keyword?

Tags: typescript

In one of the TSC project that I am working on, there is a lot of use of "n" as below.  Would anyone have any idea what is this "n"?  Refer: `z + 1n`

```
const divUp = (x: bigint, y: bigint) => {
  const z = x / y
  if (y * z == x) {
    return z
  } else {
    return z + 1n
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 3):

That's notation for a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) literal. It's not TypeScript-specific - it's JavaScript syntax.

1n is a BigInt containing 1.

5n is a BigInt containing 5. And so on.

Since `z` is a BigInt, mathematical operations can only be performed with `z` and another BigInt, so it has to be `+ 1n` instead of `+ 1`.